# How to cast string column as int in OrderBy extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I'm using a generic method to sort an `IQueryable` collection which uses the `Queryable.OrderBy` and `LambdaExpression` methods:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<SortParameter> sortParameters)
{
    IOrderedQueryable<T> sourceOrderedQueryable = sortParameters[0].SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending
            ? Queryable.OrderBy(source, (dynamic)CreateExpression<T>(sortParameter[0].ParameterName))
            : Queryable.OrderByDescending(source, (dynamic)CreateExpression<T>(sortParameter[0].ParameterName));

    // ... Same with Queryable.ThenBy

    return sourceOrderedQueryable;
}

private static LambdaExpression CreateExpression<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var modelParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    Expression body = Expression.PropertyOrField(modelParameter, sortParameter);
    return Expression.Lambda(body, modelParameter);
}


query.OrderBy(sortParameters)   // for ProductId sortParameter (string type in db) should sort as int
```

This works fine but I have to parse one column from the sorted model from string to int, something like:

```
OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ProductId))
```

I have no idea how to integrate the above conversion into this generic mechanism and the lambda expression for a specific case. Is it possible for this mechanism to converting one column (property) type?

Comment: See maybe it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984919/convert-string-to-int-for-ordering-using-linq

Comment: Try something like followingt : OrderBy(x =>  ProductId.ToCharArray().All(y => char.IsDigit()) ? x.Convert.ToInt32(ProductId) : ProductId)

Comment: From your code I see that you are not so familiar with Expression Tree building.  Try to use this extension [ApplyOrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850085/10646316) instead.

Comment: Thanks for help, I changed that Expression Tree